# Convert from Stata to LaTeX

Tags: output

I have the following in Stata:

```
    . xttab saving

                  Overall             Between            Within
   saving |    Freq.  Percent      Freq.  Percent        Percent
----------+-----------------------------------------------------
 Non-save |    7994     61.72      2269     77.44          79.99
    Saver |    4957     38.28      1640     55.97          67.99
----------+-----------------------------------------------------
    Total |   12951    100.00      3909    133.41          74.96
                              (n = 2930)
```

Please could you help me to copy this into LaTeX?

For example I tried the following but it did not work:

```
. estpost xttab saving
invalid subcommand
r(198);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome! Can you show us what you've tried? Just posting something you'd like other people to produce for you isn't really how the site is meant to work. But I may also have misunderstood your question. What is the error message from? What are you trying to do when you get that error exactly?

Comment: This question is not really about TeX/LaTeX but rather about Stata (from which you want to export LaTeX).  You might be better off asking this question on another site.  Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear @cfr! So the table below "xttab saving" is what I produced in Stata and what I would like to copy into LaTeX. In Stata I tried the "estpost xttab saving" command, hoping this would enable me to post into LaTeX. However, "estpost" is not compatible with "xttab". I am unsure of how to present the table in LaTeX. Please let me know if any further clarification is required, thanks

Comment: @HenriMenke We have other questions about conversion e.g. from Excel or Word etc. Are you sure this is off-topic?

Comment: @cfr Only because these have answers doesn't mean they are on-topic.

Comment: I know Stata can export to (horrible) latex code (I've cleaned up one of those). Have you Googled this and had a look at what Stata is able to export? I've never seen Stata myself so I cannot help there I just know that it is possible.

Comment: @HenriMenke Too early to close. If OP has only five tables like this, let's give her a helping hand. If she's got a hundred, let's discuss how to import certain data into a LaTeX tabular. Maybe the data can exported to something datatool can manage.

Comment: @RoseSimmons Google says you can export stata to Excel. From excel there are some ways to create maintainable LaTeX code.

Comment: @KeksDose Maybe you are right. But IMHO the question currently only shows a problem with the export of Stata. If it also is a question about how to manually transform the ASCII export, this should be clearly said. Nevertheless, I've added an answer about manual conversation (but I do not like it myself, so maybe I'll delete it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only this tabular or a small amount, you could convert it by hand, e.g. into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|rSrSS}
 & \multicolumn2c{Overall} & \multicolumn2c{Between} & \multicolumn1r{Within}\\
   saving &    {Freq.} &  {Percent} & {Freq.} & {Percent} & {Percent}\\
\hline
 Non-save &    7994  &   61.72  &    2269 &  77.44 &         79.99\\
    Saver &    4957  &   38.28  &    1640 &  55.97 &         67.99\\
\hline
    Total &   12951  &  100.00  &    3909 & 133.41 &         74.96\\
\multicolumn6c{(n = 2930)}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I've used [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for some of the number columns, because it is often recommended for such columns. Nevertheless, in the example above you could replace the `S`-columns by `r`-columns and would get:

[image: without siunitx]

Usage of [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) could also be a good idea, but in this case vertical lines shouldn't be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*6r}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn2c{Overall} & \multicolumn2c{Between} & Within\\
   saving &    {Freq.} &  {Percent} & {Freq.} & {Percent} & {Percent}\\
\midrule
 Non-save &    7994  &   61.72  &    2269 &  77.44 &         79.99\\
    Saver &    4957  &   38.28  &    1640 &  55.97 &         67.99\\
\midrule
    Total &   12951  &  100.00  &    3909 & 133.41 &         74.96\\
\midrule
\multicolumn6c{(n = 2930)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, converting the ASCII art tables into LaTeX `tabular` need not always be complex. The main work was:

- counting the columns and add a `\begin{tabular}{…}` declaration before and `\end{tabular}` after the table
- (optional) add a `|` for the horizontal rule
- replace white space between columns by `&` and add `\\` at the end of rows
- replace ASCII art for horizontal rules by `\hline` (or a rule command of `booktabs`).
- use some `\multicolumn2c{…}` for the table heads that should span two columns with centered text
- optionally improve tabulars using `siunitx` or `booktabs`